# Graphhopper geocode not initialized by osm.pbf

Tags: geocode, graphhopper

i have set up a graphhopper server, it work perfectly.
direction http api working well.

but geocode API not found anything.

i use a docker container : https://hub.docker.com/r/sogorkis/graphhopper/
initialized with an osm.pbf file.

that's sounds like it missing a config step...

could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Geocoding is supported by another external program (in the case of [GraphHopper Maps](https://graphhopper.com/maps/) it is the [GraphHopper Geocoding API](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api/blob/master/docs-geocoding.md)). GraphHopper only does routing, also the maps are not served from GraphHopper, just external services.